# AngularJS - Form validation, how to scroll to first invalid input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to scroll document to first invalid input in the form on button click (without using jquery of course). What a proper (angular-way) approach for this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Consider using jquery and you can scroll to `$(".ng-invalid:first")`. Just an idea.

Comment: Yes, I can easily make this with jquery, but I believe should be another way)

Answer (score 2):

include jquery so you get the full selector ability and in your controller do

```
angular.element(".ng-invalid:first") ...
```